# Cannot Edit My Answer

Tags: support, edits

Hello,
I was trying edit an old answer I made for a question and the edit button is not appearing, only add comment.

It seems like the answer isn't my own, so I can only add comment.

The question can be found bellow.

[JasperReports: Removing duplicate values from dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697910/removing-duplicate-values-from-dataset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to edit, unless you're not logged in as you (or you have multiple accounts).

https://stackoverflow.com/users/198040/gordon

Try logging in again. If you can't log in, use the

[Can't remember your login information?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery)

link on the [/login](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) page